# Is it possible in java to parse content of Archive libraries (.a), and .so (shared object) files to retrieve human readable text?

Tags: java, parsing, io, normalization

So an example of this would be the JAVA windows PE (portable executable) parser that is able to parse windows .exe and .dll files to retrieve product name and version info, in addition to copyright information.
https://github.com/kichik/pecoff4j 
Basically you pass it a file like notepad.exe and it will return the following

```
CompanyName = Microsoft Corporation
FileDescription = Notepad
FileVersion = 6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255)
InternalName = Notepad
LegalCopyright = © Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
OriginalFilename = NOTEPAD.EXE
ProductName = Microsoft® Windows® Operating System
ProductVersion = 6.1.7600.16385
```

This tool basically uses several Java inputstream libraries to access certain bytes in a file and returns a proper ASCII representation of the original data read.

For my question, I have already tried using the following method, that returned unreadable text even though I tried normalizing it:

```
public static void readContent(String file){
          BufferedReader buff = null;
        try {
            buff = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(file)),"UTF-8"));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        while(true){
            String line=null;
            try {
                line = buff.readLine();
            } catch (IOException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if(line == null){
                break;
            }

            line =  Normalizer.normalize(line, Normalizer.Form.NFD).replaceAll("\\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}+", "");
            System.out.println(line);
}
```

If anyone can point me to the right direction if there is a possible way to achieve what I want.

Comment: Such information is, as far as I'm aware, not part of .a/.so so you naturally can't extract it

Comment: It seems like that, however it would still be nice If I was able to transform the data being read to human readable text to investigate further.

Comment: I just wanted to add something after few days of investigating, .so and .a files do actually contain copyright information and I was able to retrieve it from the files using several other means than Java code. (E.g String grep function for linux command line)

Comment: Solved the problem using java InputStream, where I go through the bytes in the file and extract the char out of it, and was able to find copyright and license information inside .o .so and .a files,

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution to my question thought i'd post it in case anyone was wandering about the answer as well. I will not be posting all my code on here for confidentiality reasons, but its as simple as:

```
 fis = new FileInputStream(file);
 bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
 PeekableInputStream pis = new PeekableInputStream(bis);
 Set<String> lines = new HashSet<String>();
 int currentByte;
 StringBuilder currentLine = null;
while (((currentByte = is.read()) != -1) && lines.size() < 10000) {
            char ch = (char) currentByte;
            if (isStringChar(ch)) {
                if (currentLine == null) {
                    currentLine = new StringBuilder(8);
                }
                // found a char, add it to the current line
                currentLine.append(ch);
           }
}
```

So now if you look inside currentLine string and you will find information like license copyright if the original author have included them.